# Does the command "aptitude upgrade" perform a full-upgrade or a safe-upgrade on Debian?

Tags: debian, upgrade, aptitude

Both the commands `aptitude full-upgrade` and `aptitude safe-upgrade` are [documented](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch01s02.en.html), including the `dist-upgrade` alias for `full-upgrade`.

However, simply `aptitude upgrade` will also upgrade the system in some way...which does it default to? Also how would I find this for myself? `man aptitude upgrade` doesn't help.

Comment: As far as I can see, aptitude upgrade is deprecated and is equivalent to:  
    aptitude update
    aptitude safe-upgrade
It seems that in software world there usually is the "lesser evil" rule working - simpler term always means softer usage and less changes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As can be seen in the [source-code](http://sources.debian.net/src/aptitude/0.7.8-1/src/cmdline/cmdline_do_action.cc/?hl=79#L133) (but not the docs), `upgrade` is indeed an alias for `safe-upgrade`:

```
else if(!strcasecmp(argv[0], "full-upgrade") ||
  !strcasecmp(argv[0], "dist-upgrade"))
{
   default_action = cmdline_upgrade;
   // [...]
   upgrade_mode = full_upgrade;
   // [...]
   resolver_mode = resolver_mode_full;
}
else if(!strcasecmp(argv[0], "safe-upgrade") ||
  !strcasecmp(argv[0], "upgrade"))
{
   default_action = cmdline_upgrade;
   // [...]
   upgrade_mode = safe_upgrade;
   // [...]
   resolver_mode = resolver_mode_safe;
}
```